# UIPopover Issue

Tags: uitableview, uipopovercontroller

Trying to display my popover from the tableView cell that has been selected

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
 UserProfile *switchV = [[UserProfile alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:switchV];
  UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
 [pop presentPopoverFromRect:cell.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

[switchV release];

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's better if you post the code in your question and explain what's happening vs what you're expecting.

Comment: I posted it, its the pastie link :)

Comment: Is this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?  You've declared cell but are not setting it.

Comment: You need to explain where this button is and how it's related to a cell in the table view and where this code is being called from.

Comment: Okay. So the button is on the UITableViewCell with the action to call profileUser. with - (void)profileUser I am looking to present the popover with the information and display it next to the tableview cell that was selected.

Answer (score 0):

You have a button in a table view cell and you want to display a popover pointing to that cell when the button is pressed.

First, add the button to the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath using something like this:
(doesn't have to be rounded rect)

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 30)];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(profileUser:) 
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

**An important point above is that in the @selector, there is a colon after profileUser** (this tells the button to send a reference to itself as the first parameter to profileUser).  This reference can be used to figure out which cell was selected.

The profileUser: method should be something like this:

```
-(void)profileUser:(UIButton *)button
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[button superview] superview];
    //first superview is cell.contentView
    //second superview is cell

    UserProfile *switchV = [[UserProfile alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:switchV];
    UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];

    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:cell.frame inView:self.view 
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    [switchV release];
    [navController release];

    self.popoverController = pop; //save in property for later release

    [pop release];
}
```

If possible, leave the arrow direction as UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny and let it figure out the best place to put it.

**Edit:**
To show the popover with the arrow pointing up to the button instead of the cell, use this:

```
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:cell 
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

However, depending on the position of the cell on the screen, the popover may not look right underneath the button.  Use "Any" instead of "Up" unless you're sure of the results.

Also note you should save a reference to the popover controller for later release (in dealloc) otherwise the [pop release] in the method may cause a crash.  For a detailed example, see the [sample app Popovers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Popovers/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010436-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Comment: Hey man thanks! Now how would I go about showing it using the buttons frame? Say where the button is on the cell thats where it shows, right below? I tried using its frame but that only shows on the latest cell and not the others.

Comment: Updated the answer.  Not sure what you mean by "shows on the latest cell and not the others".